# "marked as duplicate" by community?

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates, community-user

A few minutes ago I flagged [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370730/) as a duplicate of an earlier one; when I came back to it, it showed as having been "marked as duplicate by Steven Stadnicki, Community".  I've never seen the Community bot mark duplicates before; is this new behavior? What triggers it?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the "Community" text and it says "This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote."

Comment: D'oh. I completely missed that; thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For ease of future reference I quote a part of the announcement [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) below.

---

[T]he banner shown to askers whose questions have attracted at least one duplicate close vote has a couple of ... options:

[image: That solved my problem! / No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how]

If the author clicks the first button, they're shown a confirmation that clarifies the results of this action somewhat:

[image: This will mark your question as a duplicate, directing future readers to the original question and preventing further answers from being posted here.]

If they click "Ok", the question is instantly closed:

[image: Community: This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote.]

If, instead, they edit, they'll be offered this guidance:

[image: Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question. If the answers there do not address your problem, please edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique.]

...and once an edit is submitted the choice will go away until another duplicate close-vote is cast.

Comment: The use of "Community" here is quite misleading. It should instead say "Author".

Comment: Yes, quite misleading.